# graphql Error: Introspection must provide input type for arguments, but received: [AccommodationPictureMeta]

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

i am new in GraphQL, i didn't get how to debug this issue

this is my grphql schema

```
input AccommodationInput {
  id: ID @globalId(decode: ID)
  "The name of the Accommodation."
  name: [I18nDescription!]
  "The status of the Accommodation."
  "The Meta of the Accommodation"
  meta: [AccommodationMeta!]
}

extend type Mutation @guard @namespace(field: "App\\GraphQL\\Accommodation\\Mutations") {
  "Create an Accommodation."
  accommodationCreate(input: AccommodationInput!): AccommodationCreatePayload
    @field(resolver: "AccommodationCreateMutation")
}
```

When i sync schema in frontend, it's throwing an error

> frontend@0.1.0 download-schema node scripts/downloadSchema.mjs
> Error: Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing "data" property of introspection response and no "errors" was returned alongside: undefined.

when i define `AccommodationPictureMeta` type and new error is comming

```
type AccommodationPictureMeta {
     id: ID!
     "The Upload picture custom alt value."
     alt: String!
    }
```

> frontend@0.1.0 download-schema node scripts/downloadSchema.mjs
> Error: Introspection must provide input type for arguments, but
> received: [AccommodationPictureMeta].

can you please help me to debug and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GraphQL Specification](https://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sel-FAHhBJABAB2F3zN):

> A GraphQL Input Object defines a set of input fields; the input fields are either scalars, enums, or other input objects.

In short, your `meta` field in `AccommodationInput` should be itself an input (eg. `AccommodationMetaInput`)